# Angular 7 - *ngFor calculate and bind last 3 days time in single p tag

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to calculate and display last 3 days remaining time in a 
    single p tag using angular

```
<p>You have remaining time <span *ngFor="let item of _objAttendancePage.Attendancelist">{{item.remainingTime}}</span>  to complete your working hour. Do you want to still punch out ?|</p>
```

After run above this code output is like this: 
    You have remaining time 00:25:20,00:30:25,00:40:15 Min to complete your working 
    hour. Do you want to still punch out ?

```
I expect if user logout his session before working hrs completed(last 3 days)

Employee Remaining Time List (Attendancelist: array):
1st Day: 00:25:20,
2nd Day: 00:30:25,
3rd Day: 00:40:15,
4th Day: 01:50:15 and so on
```

I Expect The Final Output Is:

```
You have remaining time 95Min to complete your working hour. Do you want 
to still punch out ?
```

Comment: Can you show us some code and point out where you are stuck?

Comment: post your trying

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to sum all the min's inside "Attendancelist" and then display the final sum value.

you should use Angular Pipe for this. it will be something like this

```html
<p>You have remaining time 
<span >{{_objAttendancePage.Attendancelist|sum}}</span>  
to complete your working hour. Do you want to still punch out ?|</p>
```

here the '|sum' is the pipe which you need to create. refer this https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Comment: Hi Ravin, I want to display 3 day remaining time as separate

Comment: Can you provide example output. Not able to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful you @Vikas. My solution HTML code below,

```
<p>I expect if user logout his session before working hrs completed(last 3 days)</p><br />
<br />
<p>Employee Remaining Time List (Attendancelist: array):</p>
<p *ngFor="let time of empRemTimes; index as day">
  Day - {{day+1}}: {{time}}<span *ngIf="empRemTimes.length!=day+1">,</span>
  <span *ngIf="empRemTimes.length==day+1"> and so on</span>
</p>
<p>You have remaining time {{sumMins}}Min to complete your working hour. Do you want fto still punch out ?</p>
```

component code below,

```
empRemTimes = ['00:01:12', '00:00:45', '00:01:00', '00:00:10'];
sumMins = 90; // SUM the above array value set this variable
```

For your ex: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8vbxa)

Final OP below,

```
I expect if user logout his session before working hrs completed(last 3 days)



Employee Remaining Time List (Attendancelist: array):

Day - 1: 00:01:12,
Day - 2: 00:00:45,
Day - 3: 00:01:00,
Day - 4: 00:00:10 and so on

You have remaining time 90Min to complete your working hour. Do you want fto still punch out ?
```

Comment: Hey Jai, thnx for valuable reply but I was resolved my problem :)